# How did Germany claim self-defense in WW1?

Tags: world-war-one, russia, international-relations, diplomacy, imperial-germany

WW1 broke out after a series of ultimatums and warnings against each other. However, I understand that every power claimed that the other powers were acting against its interests, and it was participating in the war only for self-defense.

I can understand these claims from the points of view of Austria-Hungary, Russia, and even France. Britain participated protesting against the violation of neutrality of Belgium, so even that claim is clear (at least it's not false, though it might have been just an excuse).

However, how could Germany make this claim, as it had given ultimatum to Russia against its military mobilization? How did Germany convince itself or its population that this war was only for self-defense?

Comment: I do not have any references at hand, but the expression here is "preemptive war". Germany was worried about a two front war; giving time to both Russia and France to mobilize and attack (even if the German Armhy was itself mobilized) meant almost secure defeat. The German strategy (Schlieffen plan) was based in quickly defeating France while Russia was still mobilizing.

Comment: Because 9 million Russian soldiers attacked them? You know the Russians didn't just "mobilize", they INVADED Prussia with an army of 9 million soldiers headed up by a General who publicly stated he was going to obliterate Germany.

Comment: @TylerDurden When did this happen? And why did Germany give ultimatum to Russia to stop "mobilization" rather than fighting right away to reclaim the invaded East Prussian territories?

Comment: @TylerDurden: Nonsense! from *Guns of August*, Barbara Tuchman, 1962, pages 56 & 268: While full Russian mobilization was expected to field ~6.5 million men, only 800,000 would be available on M+15 and only half of those (ie roughly 200,000 each) in the Russian First and Second armies which on that day invaded East Prussia. Note also that full Russian mobilization was not scheduled to complete until M+90, which as it turned out was 6 weeks after the Western front had settled into trench warfare awaiting replenishment of ammunition stocks.

Comment: All parties joined this war, in the short of it, because they **wanted** to join it for their own reasons: Britain to defeat the German Kriegsmarine; France to recover Alsace Lorraine; Germany to increase its share from the partition of Poland and thus increase its buffer against Russia (*Lebensraum* sound familiar); Austria to re-assert it's authority in the Balkans; Turkey to likewise re-assert its authority in the Balkans. Russia to assert its authority in the Balkans,redeem itself after the debacle of 1904, and similarly expand its holdings in Poland and Galicia.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The Russia army attacked Prussia, crossing the border on August 7th.  Germany did not attack an allied power (France) until August 23rd, more than two weeks later. The Russians began mobilizing their forces in a way that made war certain on July 24th, more than a week before anything that Germany did.

Comment: @TylerDurden: But with a total strength less than 1/20 of that which you claim; and on August 17 not August 7th (Tuchman, pp 268).

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The Russian 1st and 2nd army consisting of an estimated force between 500,000 and 1 million men first entered Prussia territory on August 7th, 1914. The fact that only a portion of the total Russian forces actually invaded is irrelevant. It was the first contact between the major belligerant powers. The OP asked how the Germans could present themselves as acting in "self defense", I answered that in a way that I think is pretty clear. Your nitpicking numbers here and there does not change the fact that the Russians were the first to attack the Germans, not the other way around.

Comment: @TylerDurden: Yet German forces had invaded Belgium in the wee hours of Aug. 4, and the Reichstag had declared war, voted a war bond, and "dissolved itself for the duration" that afternoon.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Belgium was a neutral country, not one of the belligerants. Also, Russia had no treaty with Belgium, so it was not a causus belli for Russia anyway. At the time Belgium was invaded, Russia already had men under arms in large numbers marching towards Prussia. It was Germany's point of view that it was threatened with a certain allied attack which was already in motion against it. That was their claim of "self-defense".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**By naming Russian mobilisation as the initial aggression.**

---

One needs to look no further than the [German declaration of war](http://wwi.lib.byu.edu/index.php/The_German_Declaration_of_War_on_Russia) itself. That document succinctly laid out Berlin's position that *the Russian mobilisation was an **existential threat** as well as an **act of aggression** towards Germany.* Presenting Germany as a peaceful mediator, it claims that:

> [Russia] proceeded to a general mobilisation of her forces both on land and sea. In consequence of this **threatening** step ... the German Empire was **faced by a grave and imminent danger**. If the German Government had failed to guard against this peril, they would have compromised the safety and **the very existence** of Germany. The German Government [therefore insisted] upon a cessation of the aforesaid military acts. Russia having refused to comply [have shown] that her action was **directed against Germany**

The document ended by explicitly portraying the Germany *as **answering** a challenge to fight*. A challenge which, according to the German government, Imperial Russia had issued by mobilising.

> His Majesty the Emperor, my august Sovereign, in the name of the German Empire, **accepts the challenge**, and considers himself at war with Russia.

Germany thus portrayed herself as a victim of Russian aggression, and her subsequent military actions "self-defence".

---

The German argument was not a stretch to make in 1914. Countries did not (and do not) [mobilise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobilization) for fun. In an age of mass conscript armies, **mobilisation was *the* key stage in the ramp up to war**. The tight coupling of mobilisation with war was such that it was effectively regarded as an act of war in and of itself. In Russia specifically,

> The idea that mobilization was not a peaceful act but **'the most decisive act of war'** had been present in the thought of Russian officers since 1892. The 1912 the European military districts were told to regard mobilization as the opening of hostilities.
>
> **<sub>- Strachan, Hew. *The Outbreak of the First World War.* Oxford University Press, 2004.</sub>**

Moreover, [Russia was allied to France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franco-Russian_Alliance) by an accord that was understood, **by both sides**, to mean that mobilisation guaranteed a war on two fronts for Germany.

> General N. N. Obruchev, Russia's signatory, explained [Article 2 to mean], 'this mobilisation of France and Russia would be followed immediately by positive results, by acts of war, in a word would be **inseparable from an "aggression"**'. Or as France's counterpart to Obruchev, General Raoul de Boisdeffre, put it after signing the accord, **"the mobilization is the declaration of war."**
>
> <sub>- McMeekin, Sean. *July 1914: Countdown to War.* Basic Books, 2014.</sub>

In the mindset of 1914 Europe, therefore, the Russian mobilisation essentially meant war. This also meant that the German ultimatum for Russia to cease its mobilisation would not have detracted from the self defence argument. If anything, it strengthened it - Germany could present itself as having explored all changes for peace before before "accepting" the Russian challenge to fight.

---

**Disclaimer:** Whether the German rationale is objectively correct is of course an entirely different matter. This answer also no commentary on the (in)accuracy of the other Great Powers' claims for a righteous [*casus beli*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_belli), either.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that, if Germany sat and waited while Russia mobilized, the Germans believed they would be crushed between France and Russia.

Imperial Russia was considered to be a powerful nation because they could put so many men in the field. Russia's inability to properly equip or supply them was not properly understood.

The German war plan was to overwhelm France before Russian strength could be massed against Germany. France also knew the odds and directed railway investment into Russia as long as the railways led to the European frontier [Tuchman, *Guns of August*], in order to reduce the time it would take for Russia to mobilize and apply her forces against Germany.

Comment: But the war began, correct me if I'm wrong, when Austria declared war on Serbia. And Russia had a treaty to defend its fellow Slavs in Serbia. The reason that Germany felt hemmed in with the triple alliance of Russia, France and Britain (later Italy too) ranged against her, many would argue, was because of her imperial ambitions (e.g. intention of creating a navy that would rival Britain's) and belligerent hegemony in the Middle East and North Africa.

Comment: @WS2 That's not correct. Russia had no treaty obligations to defend Serbia. Russia defended Serbia because the Tsar claimed to be the protector of all Slavs. It was an exercise in pan-nationalism. It is also worth noting that had Germany gone to war a decade earlier, no one in Europe could have stopped her (they barely did in 1914 after years of catching up). The classical narrative of blaming German belligerence must be tempered with the fact that the victorious powers were *the* great imperial powers.

Comment: Germany had the opportunity to split Russia from France. Bismarck energetically sought to use it, with the League of the Three Emperors (1873) and the Reinsurance Treaty (1887). In 1890, after Bismarck had fallen from power, Russia asked to renew the Reinsurance Treaty; Wilhelm II and his cabinet were not interested. Russia then began to move toward France. This, more than in 1914, was where the Germans really went wrong, ensuring that they would be fighting facing both ways and "shackled to a corpse."

Comment: @Semaphore Sorry I had forgotten that Russia had no formal treaty with Serbia. But it was part of the strong pan-Slavist sentiment in the face of Ottoman and Habsburg hegemony of the previous decades. The victors may well have been the great imperial powers but it is difficult to argue that this had ever been at the expense of Germany or Austria. The only expansionism within Europe between 1815 and 1914 had been Bismarck's adventures in Denmark, France, and the carving up of Poland. Remember France was minus Alsace and Lorraine.

Comment: @Semaphore And it's worth noting that France only started shooting when German soldiers were marching through France; Britain only after Germany had invaded neutral Belgium, her ally. If you are prepared to go back to Napoleon you may evince in me some sympathy for the German states. But German narcissism, thinking of themselves as a master-race, long predates Hitler.

Comment: @WS2 My point about empires was that it was the powers who held all the imperial territories, complaining about another rising start trying to scrap together pieces of whatever was left... As for France, your view is extremely biased. France entered the war for revanchism, the desire to seek revenge for 1871. French participation began the moment she mobilised her forces with Russia, **in accordance with their treaty for attacking Germany**. Refer to my answer: *"[A]s France's ... General Raoul de Boisdeffre, put it after signing the accord, 'the mobilization is the declaration of war.'"*

Comment: @Semaphore You think it was France who fired the first shots at Germany do you?

Comment: @WS2 Did you even attempt to understand the subtleties I have been pointing out? Germany could either attack before France and Russia finished mobilising, or she could wait for them to finish preparations and attack *like they'v been saying they were going to do for a decade*. Who fired the first shot is not a meaningful measure of anything in a situation where **all sides** were already committed to war.

Comment: @WS2 The first battles in the East and the West were on the German side of the border.  It was the French/Russian plan to attack the Germans and defeat them early, which they tried and eventually failed at.  The desire to define one side or the other as aggressive gets tiring.  By 1914 the two coalitions were dedicated to duking it out and that's that.

Comment: @Oldcat Two important features distinguish those times from our own experience of the Cold War. a) there was no international secretariat - like the UN. and b) no one had nuclear weapons. Another major problem was that the process of unification (Germany) was greatly aided by foreign wars. The spectre of the  "enemy at the gates" had been essential to Bismarck's policies. And that is where the whole problem started. The nineteenth century had been such a peaceful time in Europe.

Comment: @Oldcat I believe the term *zeitgeist* quintessentially describes Germany from the revolutions of 1848 to the outbreak of WWI. (The term has of course taken on a far wider currency, and is attributed to Georg Hegel. What he actually said was *Der Geist seiner Zeit*). But the original *zeitgeist*, the outlook of the new and fashionable German bourgeoisie, took in Germany's late industrialisation, spirited unification and a plunge into nationalism. The origins of WWI, in my view, are almost entirely contained in Germany's desperate attempt to catch up as a modern industrial state.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a long time, and I have already accepted an answer, and I am satisfied with it. But I'm reading *The Guns of August* right now, and I discovered following small facts. It's not a very important things, because the nations were already set on a collision course, but I think they are worth noting anyway.

Germany had developing [Schlieffen Plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlieffen_Plan) against France for several years, in which France was to be attacked via Belgium (and Luxembourg). Germany had made repeated attempts, direct or otherwise, to gauge the British response if Germany violated Belgian neutrality. Britain was however committed to the neutrality and made it clear (to both Germany as well as France, but in different tone) that whoever violates Belgian neutrality would not have British support.

Secondly, when it was clear that the war on the Eastern Front was inevitable in the last couple of days of July 1914, because of Austria-Serbia-Russia crisis, German high command (especially the Kaiser) seriously contemplated abandoning the Schlieffen Plan, and attacking Russia instead. They even asked France whether it would remain neutral in a Russo-German war, but it replied that "France would take an action in its own interests". This formal interaction, in my opinion, gives *some kind of legitimacy* to the war against France. In either case, [von Moltke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmuth_von_Moltke_the_Younger), who himself was very much committed to the plan, managed to convince Kaiser that the military commitments to the plan were irreversible, and thus Germany entered into a war on two fronts.

Source: [The Guns of August by Barbara Tuchman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guns_of_August).